# What functions can be obtained as a convolution of a Schwartz function and a tempered distribution?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, nuclear-spaces

Let $\mathcal S (\mathbb R)$ denote the space of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal S^* (\mathbb R)$ denote the dual space of Schwartz (a.k.a tempered)  distributions.
We consider $\mathcal S (\mathbb R)$ as a Frechet space and $\mathcal S^* (\mathbb R)$ as a direct limit of Banach spaces.

Let $c:\mathcal S (\mathbb R) \otimes \mathcal S^* (\mathbb R) \to  \mathcal S^* (\mathbb R)$ be the convolution map. Let  $\hat c:\mathcal S (\mathbb R) \hat\otimes \mathcal S^* (\mathbb R) \to  \mathcal S^* (\mathbb R)$ be its extention to the completed tensor product. We have an argument that "proves" the following contradictory facts:

1. $\mathrm{Im} (c)=\mathrm{Im} (\hat c)$
2. $$\mathrm{Im} (c)=(f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)|\exists \text{ a polinomial }p \text{ s.t. } \forall n\in \mathbb N \text{ the function } \frac{f^{(n)}}{p} \text{ is bounded}  )$$
3. $$\mathrm{Im} (\hat c)=(f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)|\forall n\in \mathbb N, \exists \text{ a polinomial }p \text{ s.t. }  \text{ the function } \frac{f^{(n)}}{p} \text{ is bounded}  )$$
4. $\mathcal T_u(\mathbb R) \subsetneq \mathcal T(\mathbb R)$, were $\mathcal T_u(\mathbb R)$ is the r.h.s of (1) and $\mathcal T(\mathbb R)$ is the r.h.s of (2).

What of those statments are true and what are wrong? Do you have references for any of them?

Comment: Would you mind to show the argument?

Comment: Things in 4 are not defined.

Comment: To Dirk, it is rather long, we now write it in details and if we will not find the mistake I will upload it.

Comment: To Mrc Plm, Do you mean $\mathcal T_u(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathcal T(\mathbb R)$? As I said:

$$T_u(\mathbb R)=(f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)|\exists \text{ a polinomial }p \text{ s.t. } \forall n\in \mathbb N \text{ the function } \frac{f^{(n)}}{p} \text{ is bounded}  )$$
$$T(\mathbb R)=(f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)|\forall n\in \mathbb N, \exists \text{ a polinomial }p \text{ s.t. }  \text{ the function } \frac{f^{(n)}}{p} \text{ is bounded}  )$$


Comment: I do not believe Im$(c)=$Im$(\hat{c})$. I have not checked but the statements 2. and 3. look plausible.

Comment: I would have a look at MR0517765: This says that
$$C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \hat{\ast} C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) = C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}).$$
So both maps have dense image. I am not sure why you expect that $c$ has closed image, why should every distribution be the product of a distribution and a Schwartz function, simply because you can use Fourier transform.

Comment: The last sentence was not clear: I want to say that I think that 1 is wrong, since the Fourier transforms $\phi \ast \delta$ is the product of the Fourier transforms. Certainly not every distribution is a product of a Schwartz function and distributions, since this would give the distribution rather restrictive growth conditions probably similar to $T_u$ and $T$. So $\widehat{c}$ is surjective, but $c$ is not.

Comment: To Mrc Plm.
I do not expect $c$ or $\hat c$ to have a closed image. I understand that both maps have dense image. I do not think that $\hat c$ is surjective. Note that although  the source of $\hat c$ is a complete space, it does not mean that the image of $\hat c$ is closed. There are many examples of dense image maps between complete spaces (see follow up comment). 

Comment: To Mrc Plm (follow up comment).
One such example is related to the Dixmier-Malliavin Theorem that you have mentioned: Let $c':C^{\infty}_c \otimes C^{\infty}_c \to C^{\infty}$ be the convolution map and $\hat c':C^{\infty}_c \hat \otimes C^{\infty}_c \to C^{\infty}$ be its extention to the completion. Then $Im(c)=Im(\hat c)=C^{\infty}_c \neq C^{\infty}$. I believe that our situation is similar but I cant figure out what the image is in our case.


Comment: Okay, I suspected already that convergence in the completed tensor-product topology isn't the same as convergence in the range.

Comment: Note that the space you call $T(\mathbb{R})$ is more commonly called $\mathcal{O}_M$. It has a canonical locally convex topology w.r.t. which convolution is a separately continuous bilinear map $\mathcal{S}\times\mathcal{S}'\to\mathcal{O}_M$. By some abstract argument (both $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}'$ are barrelled) it follows that this map is even hypocontinuous (meaning it is continuous on $\mathcal{S}\times B$ and $C\times\mathcal{S}'$ for all bounded subsets $B$,$C$)...

Comment: ... I'm not sure since I do not know topological tensor products well-enough but I think the latter implies that $\ast:\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{S}'\to\mathcal{O}_M$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question in the title is:
{Fourier
$(\phi u)$}
$_{\phi\in \mathscr S, u\in \mathscr S'}$.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late and far from answering all your questions but perhaps still worth mentioning:

A proof of the inclusion ${\rm Im}(c)\subseteq$ RHS of item 2) can be found in "Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions" by John Horváth. See in particular Proposition 4.11.7 on page 420.

BTW, as Johannes Hahn said the standard notation of for RHS of item 3) is $\mathcal{O}_M$. That for the RHS of item 2) is $\mathcal{O}_C$.